# C++ Hello World Error

Tags: c++

As one can see, I am just starting out with C++ and just began my hello world program.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << end1;
    cout << "Hooray!" << end1;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

But for some reason, unknown to me, I am getting an error on both of the `cout` lines, saying `end1` was undeclared! How do I fix this?

Comment: Also, get rid of the silly and dangerous [`system("PAUSE");`](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html).

Comment: How is it dangerous? Just wondering, and trying to learn more!

Comment: It's dangerous because you don't know what `pause` is supposed to do. In Windows it works as wonders, but in Linux it's not defined and could be defined by someone else. I use it anyway for simple test programs because it does what it needs to in Windows and just gets ignored in Linux.

Comment: OK, thanks. What about on Mac?

Comment: I've never programmed on a Mac so I wouldn't know...

Comment: Using system just for pausing? It is absurd! Use other functions like `getch`, `_getch`, `getchar`, `cin.getline`, or event `scanf` to wait for keyboard input! But in reality, you shouldn't use any of them. The program is finished, just leave it.

Comment: Note that in C++ (and recent versions of C), it isn't necessary for `main` to `return 0`, as discussed [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-c) - zero is returned by default.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
end1
```

should be:

```
endl
```

You used a `1` (the number) instead of `l` (the letter).

Comment: Thanks, the book was very unclear and the typeface makes them look exactly the same! Stupid me!

Comment: I thought he was using a capital-I (eye).

Answer (score 3):

that’s endL just like end LINE :P

Answer (score 3):

It should be `endl` (end line), not `end1` (end one?):

```
cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
cout << "Hooray!" << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

`endl` represent end line, it is not end1.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. Try `endl` instead of `end1`.

Answer (score 2):

You should write `endl` instead of end1 (So make the one to a small "L")

Answer (score 2):

It should be `endl` and not end1.

Answer (score 0):

replace end1 by endl and it'll work just fine! :)

Comment: Any particular reason why you answered this almost a year after the accepted answer which states exactly the same?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid typos like the one you experienced, 
instead of using "endl", you can use 'new line' by inserting '/n' inside the quote.

Example:

```
cout << " Hi, this is how you do it /n";
```

Comment: ^^ I think you mean `\n`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to replace your

```
     end1
```

with

```
    endl
```

Thus you have a syntax error that you need to fix by replacing the one('1') with an 'l', thereby fixing your program. It should compile and run successfully now.